# android startActivity Nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

hi the function startActivity throws a nullpointer exception
this is my class:

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    }

    public void showHtml(String prod){

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:allowBackup="false">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.xxxx.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"         >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.xxxx.fragments.frag1.BarcodeInsertActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.xxxx.fragments.frag2.ShopBasketActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.xxxx.fragments.frag3.CheckoutActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.xxxx.fragments.frag4.DetailActivity" />  
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:label="ZXing"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is how i try to execute the function

```
 DetailActivity gg= new DetailActivity();

gg.showHtml( "some html code <div class='someclass'>asdas</div> and other html tags");
```

would be nice if some could help me tried a lot of things nothing worked :)

Comment: Don't create object for the Activity  DetailActivity gg= new DetailActivity();

Comment: From where you are doing this...DetailActivity gg= new DetailActivity();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DetailActivity is just that, an Activity. You cannot access methods in it as you would an object. The only way to do so is to make that method static and do D`etailActivity.showHtml()` but this is *not* recommended.

The other problem is that you are not creating that Activity properly. You need to start it as an intent like so:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Then you should either access that method in that activity, or pass the variables through in a bundle like so:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("webAdd", string);
newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

You can then access this in the DetailActivity by doing the following:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String newString = bundle.getString("webAdd");
```

I suggest reading up some tutorials on how Activies work however.

Answer (score 0):

In android you don't need to write

```
DetailActivity gg= new DetailActivity();
```

You are already in they write activity and you don't need this any more.

You also need to put this activity into your manifest xml file

```
DetailActivity
```